# DataTable date columns

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

I am creating column in DataTable like :

```
headerTable.Columns.Add(VendInvoice.Date, typeof(???));
```

I dont know how can i add just a date column, I know how to add dateTime column.

Comment: Why would you need to? Can't you just use a `DateTime` without setting the time?

Comment: I dont want add time to my that field.

Comment: DateTime.Today gives you the Date with time 00:00:00

Comment: so you guys are saying that ther is not such thing as just Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type in the BCL that implements just a date with no time.

Even if there were, the `DataColumn` class wouldn't support it.  [Here is the list of types you're allowed to use.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx)  For chronological data you have `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` - that's it.

What you can do, if you want to pass this `DataTable` to callers who may not be aware of the desired date-only semantics, is attach an event handler to the `DataTable` itself which resets the time of day:

```
private void DataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Action & DataRowAction.Add) != 0) ||
        (e.Action & DataRowAction.Change) != 0))
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)e.Row[DateColumn];
        if (dt != dt.Date)
            e.Row[DateColumn] = dt.Date;
    }
}

// Later ...
dataTable.RowChanged += DataTable_RowChanged;
```

Note that the conditional logic is necessary to prevent infinite recursion in the event handler.

I really don't think I'd do this, to be perfectly honest.  Instead I would just use the `DateTime.Date` method when *accessing* the value in the column, as opposed to worrying about what happens when it's written.  But if for some reason your domain rules don't allow you to take that approach, you can use the handler above.